# Datagridview row invisible, row selection random

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the below sub to make specific rows invisible, but when I go back to the filtered datagridview and try to cycle through the visible row indices it goes from top of the column to the bottom of the column instead of going in sequence (1,2,3...and so on).

I've able to set the current set after the filter to the top visible row, but that doesn't make a difference.

```
    Private Sub BR_VAL_NO_SHOW()

    Dim dgv As DataGridView = Me.dgvStockCheck_Available
    Dim cm1 As CurrencyManager = CType(BindingContext(dgv.DataSource), CurrencyManager)

    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1

            If IsDBNull(dgv.Rows(i).Cells("MATERIAL").Value) Then
                Exit Try
            Else

                If Not dgv.Rows(i).Cells("MATERIAL").Value = "SLAT" Then
                    dgv.CurrentCell = Nothing
                    cm1.SuspendBinding()
                    dgv.Rows(i).Visible = False
                End If
            End If

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is completely normal

You give the current cell the value of `NOTHING`

But you use the `IsDBNull` to verify which isn't the same thing.

> Do not confuse the notion of **Nothing** in an object-oriented programming
>   language with a DBNull object. In an object-oriented programming
>   language, **Nothing** means the absence of a reference to an object.
>   **DBNul**l represents an **uninitialized variant** or **nonexistent database
>   column.**

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.90).aspx

So a solution could be to just check if visible or not.

```
If dgv.Rows(i).Visible = False Then
    'Not Visible
    Exit Try
Else
```